# What are those tilting/rotating platforms called that hold spacecraft during assembly, testing, and sometimes transport?

Tags: artificial-satellite, identify-this-object, manufacturing

The first image from the BBC's [Euclid space telescope to study 'dark Universe' makes progress](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-49773022) reminded me of the second two, which are taken from [What are these air-vent-like structures on this satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15306/12102).

**Question:** What are those tilting/rotating platforms called that (usually but not always<sup>†</sup>) securely hold spacecraft during assembly, testing, and sometimes transport?

<sup>†</sup>[Was the NOAA-N Prime satellite really dropped on the floor?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1783/12102)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question asks what the name of the stands are https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34040/6944 but that's not the sole focus of the question. Possible duplicate.

Comment: "positioner" eh, well that's anticlimactic. Okay how about we let this question go around the Earth once, and if a better, more cool and technical-sounding official name can't be found and sourced, then we'll close this as duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @OrganicMarble actually I remember seeing a big communications satellite attached to one in a horizontal orientation *inside it's shipping container*. It's possible that combination (thus the "...and sometimes transport?") has a different name.

Comment: Sometimes it's just a plain old scaffold https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38900/6944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic term seems to be "positioner", sometimes with adjectives like "[trolley positioner](https://weldplus.com/product/welding-positioners/120000-lb-aronson-trolley-positioner/)"

> (The) Aronson Trolley Positioner...was specially designed by NASA to assemble and “Float on Built-In Air Pads” a 2 billion dollar spacecraft that was launched in late December 1999

or "[rotary positioner](https://www.nsi-mi.com/products/mechanical-products/rotary-positioners)". Standard commercial items exist, but perhaps the ones used for satellite assembly are custom in some way.

Comment: There we go, thanks!

Comment: fyi I've just asked [For which “2 billion dollar spacecraft launched in 1999” did NASA “specially design” an Aronson Trolley Positioner?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38986/12102)

Comment: This definitely appears now to be a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble In that case do you think it makes sense for BobJacobsen to move/add this answer there?

Comment: Sure, there's some good additional info there.  But closing as a duplicate doesn't make the answer or question go away, I'm pretty sure they can still be upvoted. It just annotates the top of the question.  I am pretty sure stuff I've dupe-hammered on scifi stack exchange still gets votes.