# For which “2 billion dollar spacecraft launched in 1999” did NASA “specially design” an Aronson Trolley Positioner?

Tags: nasa, identify-this-object

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38984/12102) to *What are those tilting/rotating platforms called that hold spacecraft during assembly, testing, and sometimes transport?* quotes this Weld Plus [website](https://weldplus.com/product/welding-positioners/120000-lb-aronson-trolley-positioner/) as follows:

> (The) Aronson Trolley Positioner...was specially designed by NASA to assemble and “Float on Built-In Air Pads” a 2 billion dollar spacecraft that was launched in late December 1999

Thee is a NASA spacecraft shown in images in that link, but I don't know if that's actually the spacecraft in question or not, so I'll defer to answers to look into that possibility.

**Question:** For which "2 billion dollar spacecraft" did NASA "specially design" an Aronson Trolley Positioner in 1999?

That's a lot of money for a spacecraft! The "120,000 lb. Aronson Trolley Positioner" was "built in 1995" and rated for

- Rotation Load Torque: 1,440,000 in-lb
- 2,880,000 in-lb

so at least we know it's bigger than a breadbox but smaller than a Space Shuttle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I nominate "[Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_%28satellite%29)" launched in December 1999.  2 billion dollars is a bit of a stretch perhaps - the [press kit](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/156293main_terra_press_kit.pdf) says $1.3B, but excludes a bunch of stuff.

> does not include ground system cost nor the cost of the Canadian or
>   Japanese instruments

The Terra instrument(s) annotated as CERES in this [picture](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/terra/spacecraft/index.html)...

[image]

...match well to this picture from the Weld Plus website in the question (annotation mine).

[image]

Comment: maybe it's time for a "space-detective" badge?

Comment: "identify-this-object" tag badges serve pretty well. Working on the silver!